# No Audio on HP x360 15-ey0xxx

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an HP EnvyX360 2-1 15-ey0xxx with Bang & Olufsen speakers. I just installed Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Dual Boot)on it. Everything installed fine from what I could tell.

My speakers don’t work on it. Not only that, but the system seems to think they are working and I’ve used HDAJackRetask to a post I found on here’s instructions and that didn’t fix it. I used the mixer that’s been given as a different solution, didn’t work. I’ve done updates also. Though, the headphone jack and Bluetooth works fine, just not my speakers. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Known issue. You'll have to wait for either the kernel to patch, or for HP to fix the BIOS then do a manual update.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216311